# Unit Test for Validator Directive in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am going to write some unit tests for my validator directive, but don't know how, even after googling and reading the Angular website. I will explain the codes (just the parts that are needed) here.

Here is my component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { isValidValidator } from '../../directives/is-valid.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-microplate',
  templateUrl: './microplate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./microplate.component.css']
})
export class MicroplateComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      columns: new FormControl('', [
        isValidValidator()
      ])
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my directive.ts code:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
const { isNumbersFieldValid } = require('../utils/utils.js');

export function isValidValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    return isNumbersFieldValid(control.value) ? {isValid: {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIsValid]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: IsValidDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class IsValidDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appIsValid') isValid: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return this.isValid ? isValidValidator()(control) : null;
  }
}
```

Here is my directive.spec.ts code:

```
import { IsValidDirective } from './is-valid.directive';

describe('IsValidDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new IsValidDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // How can I write some unit tests here to check if my directive works well for different input strings?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can find how to test attribute directives

https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives

basically you need to create a testComponent in your spec files and apply your directive in that testComponent, your test expectation can be done on the testComponent directly

Comment: but HOW do you test if the testComponent is valid???

Comment: @patrick what do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: @patrick testComponent is just a simple component you create for testing purpose, to only apply the directive on it, and then check if the directive works as intended, you don't need to test the testComponent.